# Displaytag table paging with tiles

Tags: struts2, tiles, displaytag

Im using displaytable with tiles. Problem is in my crud application, when I search something its loading data into display table,
and when I click on 2nd page its load data to 2nd page as I give requestURI="searchorgs". All works fine upto that,
Then I call Edit template and after submitting edited data it should load data to table. Its also work fine but when I click 2nd page
Its goes to search page as I mention in requestURI="searchorgs". I need to keep in same page with out moving to search page. Same table is insert in to add,edit,search jsp pages in tiles.xml. I dont want to define 3 separate tables for this.
Application I struts2 tiles integration one.

action class search method :

```
public String search() {
organisationSearch = new OrganisationSearch();

organisationSearch.setAoName(aoName);

orglist = orgBo.searchOrg(organisationSearch);

return "search";
```

}

Struts xml :

```
  <action name="*orgs" class="com.ast.action.admin.OraganisationAction"
            method="{1}">

            <result name="add" type="tiles">orgAddTemplate</result>

            <result name="search" type="tiles">orgTemplate</result>
            <result name="delete" type="tiles">orgTemplate</result>

            <result name="edit" type="tiles">orgEditTemplate</result>
            <r
        </action>
```

table :

```
 <s:form theme="simple" id="delete" action="deleteorgs">
    <display:table id="studentTable" name="orglist" pagesize="5" cellpadding="5px;" id="row" cellspacing="5px;"
        style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:20px;" requestURI="searchorgs">
        <display:column style="width:5px;">
            <s:checkbox name="chkBox" id="check%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}" value="%{#attr.row.chkBox}" fieldValue="%{#attr.row.aoId}" />
        </display:column>
        <display:column title="Action" style="width:10px;" value="Edit" href="vieweditorgs" paramId="aoId" paramProperty="aoId" />
        <display:column title="View" style="width:10px;" value="View" href="vieworgs" paramId="aoId" paramProperty="aoId" />
        <display:column title="Dlt" style="width:10px;" value="Dlt" href="singledeleteorgs" paramId="aoId" paramProperty="aoId" />
        <display:column property="aoId" title="ID" />
        <display:column property="aoName" title="Name" />

    </display:table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define **action** in `requesturi` programmatically.

Please see this

[dispalay tag table pass value to requestURI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203035/dispalay-tag-table-pass-value-to-requesturi/24222536#24222536)

In action class

```
 private String myActionName;

 public String search() {
      organisationSearch = new OrganisationSearch();

      organisationSearch.setAoName(aoName);

      orglist = orgBo.searchOrg(organisationSearch);
      //set action name
      myActionName="action1.action";
      return "search";

 }
 //other methods
 public void setMyActionName(String myActionName) {
    this.myActionName = myActionName;
  }

public String getMyActionName() {
    return myActionName;
}
```

In `jsp` file

```
 <display:table id="u" name="userlist"  pagesize="10"   requestURI="${myActionName}" >
  ...
 </display:table>
```

If I misunderstood your question, Please let me know.

Comment: Actually both questions are asked by the same user. BTW you are right.if link changes the answer may change.should I delete it? well I have modified it little bit.