# dispalay tag table pass value to requestURI

Tags: struts2, tiles, displaytag

How do I set value to requestURI by action class in Struts2 or another form. I need to change value of requestURI according to tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Pass value from action (Better way)**

In `yourAction.java`

```
  private String myActionName;
  public String execute() {
        myActionName="action1.action";
        return SUCCESS;
  }
  public void setMyActionName(String myActionName) {
        this.myActionName = myActionName;
  }

  public String getMyActionName() {
        return myActionName;
  }
```

In `jsp` file

```
  <display:table id="u" name="userlist"  pagesize="10"   requestURI="${myActionName}" >
  ...
  </display:table>
```

If you want to pass your own parameter in url

```
  <s:url action="%{myActionName}" var="requrl" >
        <s:param name="myparam">myvalue1</s:param>
  </s:url>
  <display:table id="u" name="userlist"  pagesize="10"   requestURI="${requrl}" >
  ...
  </display:table>
```

**Option 2: Pass value from tile (Not Recommanded)**

In `tiles.xml`

```
  <definition name="baseLayout" template="/BaseLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" type="string"  />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/Header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/Menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/Footer.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="myattribute" value="" type="string"  />
  </definition>

  <definition name="/welcome.tiles" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome" type="string" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/Welcome.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="myActionName" cascade="true" value="tileAction1.action"  />
  </definition>
```

**Note:** Use proper tiles version and `tiles.xml dtd` to use `cascade="true"`.

In `welcome.jsp`

```
  <tiles:useAttribute name="myActionName" />
  <display:table id="u" name="userlist"  pagesize="10"   requestURI="${myActionName}" >
  ...
  </display:table>
```

Comment: Thanks for well explained answer. I have tried Pass value from action method before with wrong syntax in jsp.I used requestURI="#{myActionName}" instead requestURI="${myActionName}". Thanks again to show me correct syntax.